# how to fire an event when the TAB key is pressed?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, textbox, keydown

I just want to "catch" when some user press the TAB key in a Textbox. I'm working in a simple CRUD asp.net application, c# as code behind.

I try to do this as a test:

```
private void KeyForm_KeyDown( object sender, KeyEventArgs e )
      {
         keyInfoLabel.Text =
            "KeyCode: " + e.KeyCode + '\n' +
            "KeyData: " + e.KeyData + '\n' +
            "KeyValue: " + e.KeyValue;
      }
```

But it just works with C# desktop application.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in Javascript?

Comment: ASP.NET will not respond to a keydown in the way you are describing. You have tagged your problem as asp.net, but is it perhaps a WinForms or Javascript question? You most certainly can do this in those environments.

Comment: If it's asp.net you don't want to catch this on server side, obviously. You should use JavaScript. Check the reference at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onkeydown)

Comment: @MikeChristensen I'm not using any Javascript in my application, but may be the logic can help. Thanks Mike!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%= testTextBox.ClientID%>').keydown(function (e) {
       var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
           if (code == 9) {
             $('#<%= 2ndTextBox.ClientID%>').focus()
                return false;
             }
    });
});
```

It can be useful for somebody.

regards

Answer (score 1):

TAB key can not be catched by KeyPress or KeyDown. so to achieve your requirement use Leave Event for TextBox.

In Leave Event definition move the focus back to TextBox...

like this...

`private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)` 
`{`
    `textBox1.Text="Khan Pressed the TAB";`
    `textBox1.Focus();`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#textbox').live('keydown', function(e) { 
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

  if (keyCode == 9) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    // call custom function here
  } 
});
```

use java script

Comment: FYI.. As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.